# do not display the same item twice if there is a duplicate JS

Tags: javascript, html, duplicates, gatsby

hello and **thank** to take the time to answer my question.

So there is the context :
I have created an API.
**I display the data like this :**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJ064.png

Nevertheless, I want to display the date above the sneakers name (e.g : 2020-07-04) just one time
So if a sneaker have the same date, I would like to remove the  that contains the date

**In other words I would like to have this :**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFiXO.png

So what I tried :
Actually I know how to remove a duplicate data from an array but in this case don't want to delete it, I just want to display it once :)

Do you have any **line of thought ?**

Comment: So what is your code?

Comment: Can you show us your loop through the items and how you do display them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want to do is group the data instead of filtering/removing items.

So if you started from a shape like

```
[
  {name: 'bloodline', date: '2020-07-04' },
  {name: 'celtics', date: '2020-07-04' },
  {name: 'air dior', date: '2020-07-08' },
  {name: 'bloodline 2.0', date: '2020-07-08' },
]
```

you might want to change it to something like

```
{
  '2020-07-04': [
    {name: 'bloodline', date: '2020-07-04' },
    {name: 'celtics', date: '2020-07-04' },
  ],
  '2020-07-08': [
    {name: 'air dior', date: '2020-07-08' },
    {name: 'bloodline 2.0', date: '2020-07-08' },
  ]
}
```

Or a nested array may be easier to work with in react

```
[
  {
    date: '2020-07-04',
    items: [
      {name: 'bloodline', date: '2020-07-04' },
      {name: 'celtics', date: '2020-07-04' },
    ],
  }, {
    date: '2020-07-08',
    items: [
      {name: 'air dior', date: '2020-07-08' },
      {name: 'bloodline 2.0', date: '2020-07-08' },
    ]
  }
]
```

And then you would map over the items and render just the object key or outer `date`

Lodash has a `groupBy` function that you could use (https://lodash.com/docs/#groupBy), or [here's a standalone implementation](https://gomakethings.com/a-vanilla-js-equivalent-of-lodashs-groupby-method/)

Comment: Indeed it what I did, and it works !!! thank you !! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the response from your API is something like this:

```
const data = [
  {
    title: 'bloodline',
    date: '2020-07-04'
  }, {
    title: 'celtics',
    date: '2020-07-04'
  }, {
    title: 'air dior',
    date: '2020-07-08'
  }
];
```

Then you could use [LoDash's groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy) method and make something like this:

```js
const data = [
  {
    title: 'bloodline',
    date: '2020-07-04'
  }, {
    title: 'celtics',
    date: '2020-07-04'
  }, {
    title: 'air dior',
    date: '2020-07-08'
  }
];

const grouped = _.groupBy(data, 'date');

for (let date in grouped) {
  // display date here
  console.log(date);
  
  for (let item of grouped[date]) {
    // display each item title here
    console.log(item.title);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Note: Since you haven't provided any source code, most probably you'll need to adapt this snippet to your use case, but this could be a starting point to solve it.